# Scrolling has broken in the eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I use SW4STM32 (Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)) and at some point in time scrolling stopped working in the text editor when using the mouse wheel. CTRL+ mouse wheel works fine, but it doesn't fit at all, because it scrolls too much.
Please tell me where it is configured, I searched the entire menu and did not find it.

Comment: There is no configuration for this, it is something the OS does. Note that Neon is now 5 years and 15 releases old

Comment: Try with a different mouse.

Comment: No, no, the problem is exactly in the eclipse. It's not the mouse's fault. 
This inconvenience was solved by switching to CubeIDE, it was a pity to lose all the accumulated settings.